# Transforming Hash with Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a simple hash that looks like this one:

```
{"12"=>[1], "10"=>[1], "2"=>[1], "11"=>[1]}
```

key is equal to User name and value is equal to User followers ids.
Now I want to transform this hash to return me data like the following:

```
{"User 12"=>[Follower name], "User 10"=>[Follower name], "User 2"=>[Follower name], "User 11"=>[Follower name]}
```

What will be the best way do to this in Ruby?

Comment: And where shall the names come from?

Comment: When You want to get Follower name: Follower.find(id).name. But this is not important. I'm only looking for example and I will apply to my needs.

Comment: Shall the keys be looked up too? You write "key is equal to User name" but in your example, it seems it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
hash = {"12"=>[1], "10"=>[1], "2"=>[1], "11"=>[1]}
hash.each_with_object({}) do |(user_id, follower_ids), hash|
  hash[User.find(user_id).name] = follower_ids.map { |follower_id| Follower.find(follower_id).name }
end
```

I've used `User` and `Follower` as `ActiveRecord` classes, but this depends on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

This will transform your hash in-place:

```
hash.values.each { | ids | ids.map! { | id | ... code to transform id to name ... } }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
res = {}
hash =  {"12"=>[1], "10"=>[1], "2"=>[1], "11"=>[1]}
hash.each{ |k,v| res["User #{k}"] = Follower.find(v.first).name }
res
# => {"User 12"=>Follower name, "User 10"=>Follower name, "User 2"=>Follower name, "User 11"=>Follower name}
```